# How to stop a Thread - Python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

> Hi guys, I am struggling trying to stop a thread, I don't get any error but my thread don't stop. I would appreciate some help. I have a button who call my function lev which should stop the thread when I turned my button off. Follow the part of the code below:

```
exitFlag = 0

def levt():

    print("Executando")
    while ((app.frames[Acionamento].var.get()==2) and exitFlag==0):
        print("o thread")
        t1fvm = time.time()  #Tempo final luminária esquerda
        n1mv = (t1fvm-t1ivm)*0.6
        global levm
        levm = levm+n1mv
        print(levm)




def lev():

    app.frames[Acionamento].esquerdaFrame.vendasFrame.luminaria_esquerdaFramev.label6["text"] = "Luminária A"
    global exitFlag
    global thread2
    thread2 = Thread(target=levt)    
    if GPIO.input(17):
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        app.frames[Acionamento].esquerdaFrame.vendasFrame.luminaria_esquerdaFramev.lev_button["text"]="Desligado"
        if thread2.isAlive():
            exitFlag = 1

    else:
        global t1ivm
        t1ivm = time.time()   
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        app.frames[Acionamento].esquerdaFrame.vendasFrame.luminaria_esquerdaFramev.lev_button["text"]="Ligado"
        thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `thread2` is always initiated with new thread inside `lev()`, so `if thread2.isAlive()` will be always evaluated as `False` and `exitFlag` will never be set to 1.  Therefore the running thread will never be stopped.

Move `thread2 = Thread(target=levt)` to line before `thread2.start()`:

```
def lev():
    ...
    #thread2 = Thread(target=levt)  # moved to line before thread2.start()
    if GPIO.input(17):
        ...
    else:
        ...
        thread2 = Thread(target=levt)
        thread2.start()
```

Comment: Thanks ACW, I got it and solved it. One more question how can I convert seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

Comment: Is `seconds` the value returned by `time.time()`?  Does `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` mean the presentation of the time of `seconds` or the elapsed time?

Comment: The time.time() returns seconds or too close right? Could you give me an example?

Comment: To represent `seconds` as time: `time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(seconds))`.  To get the *elapsed time* for `seconds`: `'{}:{}:{}'.format(seconds//3600, seconds//60%60, seconds%60)`.

Comment: Thanks ACW, I am trying to represent the time I get from time.time() as elapsed time for seconds but I ma getting something like 0.0:0.0:0.0 insted of 0:0:0.